# Admin Grid Serializer - Grid in Tab Problems

Tags: admin, backend, grid, grid-serlization

I'm currently trying to add a Grid inside a Tab of its parent Grid(?).
I already have a working Grid and read through a lot of tutorials about the Grid serializer but I cant get it to work.
Here is what I got so far:

*code/local/MP/Berater/controllers/Adminhtml/**IndexController.php***

```
<?php


class MP_Berater_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $myblock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('berater/adminhtml_berater');        
        $this->_addContent($myblock);

        $this->_title($this->__('System'))->_title($this->__('Manage Form Elements'));      
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('adminhtml/session');
        $this->_setActiveMenu('Ics');

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function newAction() {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function editAction() {
        $beraterId= $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_sid');
        $beraterModel = Mage::getModel('berater/form')->load($beraterId);

        if ($beraterModel ->getId() || $beraterId== 0)
        {
            Mage::register('berater_data', $beraterModel );
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('berater/set_time');
            $this->_addBreadcrumb('Form Manager', 'Form Manager');
            $this->_addBreadcrumb('Form Description', 'Form Description');
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()
                                    ->createBlock('berater/adminhtml_berater_edit'))
                 ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('berater/adminhtml_berater_edit_tabs')
                 );
            $this->renderLayout();
        }
        else
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('Form does not exist');
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

    public function saveAction() {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost())
        {
            try {

                Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_berater_save_after');

                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $testModel = Mage::getModel('berater/form');
                if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0 )
                    $testModel->setCreatedTime(
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/date')
                            ->gmtDate()
                    );
                $testModel
                    ->addData($postData)
                    ->setUpdateTime(
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/date')
                            ->gmtDate())
                    ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                    ->addSuccess('successfully saved');
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                    ->settestData(false);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e){
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                    ->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                    ->settestData($this->getRequest()
                                       ->getPost()
                    );
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit',array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function deleteAction() {
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                $testModel = Mage::getModel('berater/form');
                $testModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))->delete();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                    ->addSuccess('successfully deleted');
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                    ->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function massDeleteAction() {
        $webIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('developers');
        if(!is_array($webIds)) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select item(s)'));
        } else {
            try {
                foreach ($webIds as $webId) {
                    $web = Mage::getModel('berater/form')->load($webId);
                    $web->delete();
                }
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                    Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__(
                        'Total of %d record(s) were successfully deleted', count($webIds)
                    )
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }
}
```

*code/local/MP/Berater/Block/Adminhtml/**Berater.php***

```
<?php

class MP_Berater_Block_Adminhtml_Berater extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_berater';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'berater';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('berater')->__('Form Elements');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('berater')->__('my button text');

    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->setChild( 'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
            $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

*code/local/MP/Berater/Block/Adminhtml/Berater/**Grid.php***

```
<?php

class MP_Berater_Block_Adminhtml_Berater_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setId('beraterGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('berater/form')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('berater')->__('ID'),
          'align'     =>'right',
          'width'     => '10px',
          'index'     => 'id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('title', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('berater')->__('Title'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'width'     => '500px',
          'index'     => 'title',
        ));


        $this->addColumn('content', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('berater')->__('Description'),
            'index'     => 'description',
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction() {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('berater');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
            'label'    => Mage::helper('berater')->__('Delete'),
            'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
            'confirm'  => Mage::helper('berater')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

*code/local/MP/Berater/Block/Adminhtml/Berater/**edit.php***

```
<?php


class MP_Berater_Block_Adminhtml_Berater_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        //we assign the same blockGroup as the Grid Container
        $this->_blockGroup = 'berater';
        //and the same controller
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_berater';
        //define the label for the save and delete button
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label','Save Form Element');
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', 'Delete Form Element');

    }
    /* Here, we're looking if we have transmitted a form object,
       to update the good text in the header of the page (edit or add) */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry('berater_data') && Mage::registry('berater_data')->getId())
        {
            return 'Editer'.$this->htmlEscape(
                Mage::registry('berater_data')->getTitle()).'<br />';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'Add Developers';
        }
    }
}
```

*code/local/MP/Berater/Block/Adminhtml/Berater/Edit/**Tabs.php***

```
<?php


class MP_Berater_Block_Adminhtml_Berater_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
    public function __construct()    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('berater_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle('Form Information');
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()    {
        $this->addTab('form_section', array(
            'label'     => 'Label Form Information',
            'title'     => 'Title Form Information',
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('berater/adminhtml_berater_edit_tab_form')->toHtml()
        ));

        $this->addTab('options', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('berater')->__('Options'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('berater/adminhtml_berater_edit_tab_options')->toHtml()
        ));

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

*code/local/MP/Berater/Block/Adminhtml/Berater/Edit/**Form.php***

```
<?php


class MP_Berater_Block_Adminhtml_Berater_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array(
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                'method' => 'post',
            )
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

*code/local/MP/Berater/Block/Adminhtml/Berater/Edit/Tab/**form.php***

```
<?php


class MP_Berater_Block_Adminhtml_Berater_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {   
        $attributeCollection = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                                ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
                                ->getAttributeCollection();

        $attributes = array();
        foreach($attributeCollection as $attribute) {
            array_push($attributes, $attribute->getName());
        }


        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('berater_form',
            array('legend'=>'Legend Form Information'));

        $fieldset->addField('title', 'text',
            array(
                'label' => 'Title',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'title'
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('description', 'textarea',
            array(
                'name'      => 'Description',
                'label'     => Mage::helper('berater')->__('Label Description'),
                'title'     => Mage::helper('berater')->__('Title Description')
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('type', 'select',
            array(
                  'label'     => 'Form Element Type',
                  'class'     => 'required-entry',
                  'required'  => true,
                  'name'      => 'type',
                  'onclick' => "",
                  'onchange' => "",
                  'value'  => '1',
                  'values' => array('1' => 'Select'),
                  'disabled' => false,
                  'readonly' => false,
                  'tabindex' => 1
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('action', 'select',
            array(
                  'label'     => 'Action',
                  'class'     => 'required-entry',
                  'required'  => true,
                  'name'      => 'action',
                  'onclick' => "",
                  'onchange' => "",
                  'value'  => '1',
                  'values' => array('1' => 'Set Attribute', '2' => 'Modify Attribute'),
                  'disabled' => false,
                  'readonly' => false,
                  'tabindex' => 1
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('attribute', 'select',
            array(
                  'label'     => 'Attribute',
                  'class'     => 'required-entry',
                  'required'  => true,
                  'name'      => 'type',
                  'onclick' => "",
                  'onchange' => "",
                  'value'  => '1',
                  'values' => $attributes,
                  'disabled' => false,
                  'readonly' => false,
                  'tabindex' => 1
            )
        );


        if ( Mage::registry('berater_data') )
        {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('berater_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to create another tab (options.php) inside `code/local/MP/Berater/Block/Adminhtml/Berater/Edit/Tab/` which contains a Grid or something with similiar functionality. I'll worry about the model when I got the block done. Of course I tried to get this done by myself (read many tutorials and articles) but I never got it working. I'm actually pretty desperate at the moment since I really want to finish this module and I'm running out of time. Hopfully someone can help me here and lead me in the right direction.